# PayPal IPN APIs and Unicode symbols in parameters

Tags: php, unicode, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm experiencing a weird issue with the [PayPal IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/) APIs. I've set up a PHP script on my site to process customer payments. That script is called by the PayPal IPN every time a payment is made for my service. In turn the script dispatches a registration email for the customer using information provided by PayPal.

This works fine, except when a PayPal user's name is not in English. Like this payment (screenshot from my PayPal page) with the name in Chinese:

[image]

The following is taken from the PayPal's "[Instant Payment Notification (IPN) history](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_display-ipns-history)" for that request generated by PayPal IPN (with the actual IDs edited out):

```
transaction_subject=&payment_date=01:22:55 Nov 11, 2014 PST&txn_type=web_accept&last_name=&residence_country=CN&item_name=service_name_here&payment_gross=1.00&mc_currency=USD&business=businessname@gmain.com&payment_type=instant&protection_eligibility=Ineligible&verify_sign=longidhere&payer_status=unverified&tax=0.00&payer_email=buyersemail@somewhere.com&txn_id=id_here&quantity=1&receiver_email=myemail@gmain.com&first_name=&payer_id=id_here&receiver_id=id_here&item_number=1&handling_amount=0.00&payment_status=Completed&payment_fee=0.08&mc_fee=0.08&shipping=0.00&mc_gross=1.00&custom=&charset=windows-1252&notify_version=3.8&ipn_track_id=some_id
```

The PHP script that handles the name is this:

```
$encoding_2_use = "utf-8";
$encoding_used = $_REQUEST['charset'];
$FirstName = mb_convert_encoding($_REQUEST['first_name'], $encoding_2_use, $encoding_used);
$LastName = mb_convert_encoding($_REQUEST['last_name'], $encoding_2_use, $encoding_used);

//Then I use $FirstName and $LastName to make up registration for the customer.

//And to compose an email
$msg = "Hello $FirstName $LastName:";
```

But what I got in the case of that Chinese name is this:

> Hello  :

or if you open it via Hex editor I could see this:

[image]

or `0x1A` characters instead of those two parts of the name in Chinese.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Since you are talking about this particular case, so could you please print out the values of `$_REQUEST['first_name']`, `$_REQUEST['last_name']` and `$encoding_used`.

Comment: @NonymousNT: Since this request is coming from PayPal IPN I obviously cannot recreate it. All I have at this point is that history data I posted above. From which we can assume that `first_name` was passed as char `0x1A` and `charset` as `windows-1252`. The interesting thing though is that if I run it through their [simulator](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator) with the same exact name, it seems to work fine.

Comment: Did you try to change the encoding format to Utf-8 in your PayPal account here https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-language-encoding

Comment: @Eshan: No, I didn't. But when I just checked, it doesn't have a UTF-8 option. It simply gives me a list of languages, which is pointless because I can't predict what country the payment may be coming from. Am I missing something?

Comment: You know, a quick follow-up. If one clicks "More options" from the page suggested above, then there's a way to select UTF-8 encoding. Although having done that, the first suggested option still doesn't change. So we'll see if that does it. I can't test it until I actually get a payment from abroad :)

Comment: Sorry i fogot to tell you to click on more option:)